# Work upon Indoor GPS maps

Tags: android

I have my own user defined maps(map images) which I want to show on Android device with incorporating functionality of google maps such as zoom in and zoom out features,markers and so on, so I am bit stuck that in which way I should proceed,is there any functionality which allow us to integrate custom images on google map view or should I opt some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay) of [Google Maps for Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). This should do what you want to achieve:

> A Tile Overlay is a set of images which are displayed on top of the
>   base map tiles. These tiles may be transparent, allowing you to add
>   features to existing maps.

Comment: I already have my custom map image on which I have to perform things like zooming and marker overlay features so should I opt for google map for this or not

Comment: Yes you should. As I understand it, using the TileOverlay you provide your own tiles which lay above Google's standard map tiles. So you just have to implement this. Zooming, markers etc. you can do with Google's API.

Comment: thanks for the feedback,I will put forward this implementation

Answer (score 0):

Google maps stop zooming in after a point. Depending on the size of the structure you have and the detail that you want to overlay this could mean that google maps are out of the question.

I would suggest that you build you own page (html), include the map photo there, and use html image map and javascript to handle a users taps. Then load this page in a webview. This will give you zoomin/zoomout functionality.

Since it is indoors map (probably a mall) you won't be able to get a usable (accurate) location so you  don't realy have to stick to a "real" map